# python remove ss from HH:MM:ss and display only HH:MM

Tags: python, regex, django, time

I have an input string like this

```
HH:MM:ss    
01:22:00
```

I want to remove seconds (ss), so that it is only

```
HH:MM
01:22
```

How can I achieve that in python ?

Comment: Read about function `str.split()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to do this using a time object you can parse the time string to a time object. From there you can spit the string back out with your formatting.

```
import time
time_obj = time.strptime("01:22:00", "%H:%M:%S")

time.strftime("%H:%M", time_obj)

>>>>'01:22'
```

This is not exactly the shortest way, but it does truly transform your string into a time object which can be added to, subtracted from, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
x= "01:22:00"
print x[:-3]

>>>'01:22'
```